# How to hook protocol method using CaptainHook

Tags: ios, tweak, theos

I did find a example for doing this using Theos Logos:

https://github.com/DHowett/theos-logos-examples/blob/master/logos.uiapplicationdelegate/Tweak.xm

But I'd like to know how to do it using CaptainHook.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter which framework you use, you always want to call `MSHookMessageEx()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use this function called `MSHookMessageEx()`.

Comment: Hi again! MSHookMessageEx() works well but when I call the original IMP I get this: exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11. any advice?

Comment: @Qusic How do you declare and call the original implementation?

Comment: @Qusic Why don't you swizzle the methods somewhere in the initialization. As currently stands, it's performed each time the action sheet is shown, I'm not sure you want that.

Comment: Ok, i will try. I dont know what kind of class the delegate is and I cant find a example for this. maybe there is some other better way to do this?

Comment: @Qusic Yet you could add a check against a `static BOOL`.

Comment: moved MSHookMessageEx to setDelegate but the same. crash only happened when original was called. Ok, I decide to search for another way now. Thanks anyway.